# Skype crashes when I run it as root user

Tags: sudo, skype

In Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkstation P330, Skype just crashes some seconds after start and writes a crash log that starts with:

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
Date: Mon Apr 20 23:40:53 2020
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux
ExecutableTimestamp: 1583231146
ProcCmdline: /usr/share/skypeforlinux/skypeforlinux\ --executed-from=/**root**\ --pid=2097
ProcCwd: /**root**
```

But it runs OK if I login and run it as a regular user.
Any clues?

Comment: Running Skype as root does not sound very wise. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: As @GunnarHjalmarsson said: it's a really bad idea to run Skype as root.

Comment: Friends, it's not the question I'm asking of, thanks.

Comment: @bobarai it might not be the question you ask, but it is the answer you will get from any experienced system administrator ... don't ever never run apps as root. And don't EVER NEVER run desktop and gui apps as root .. it is NOT needed, never. if you think you need root to run your app you are almost always doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm an experienced system administrator with more than 20 years of experience. :)

Comment: @Bobarai no offense, but being an experienced system administrator and giving a problem description like this? It does not compute. Was a core file generated (if not what's `ulimit -c`/`/etc/security/limits.conf` saying), did you load into into `gdb` ... what clues did it give? Did you check the (system) logs? Did you try this under `strace`, what insights did you gain? Sure, the points about something running "as root" are correct, but if that root is inside its own sandbox (namespaces/FireJail, VM ...), I'd also not be worried, just like you.

Comment: It'll be hard enough to work with information like a core dump _if_ you happen to get one, because there won't be debug symbols and the binary is probably statically linked and comes without source. But a minimum of information is expected from _you_, if you expect a meaningful answer beyond mere guesses. Thanks in advance for editing the requested details into your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. the core dump and gdb or truss are too heavy stuff for an interactive application. I do have a crash dump, that doesn't help much. I found some answer in Microsoft, that says to add --no-sandbox to the command line of the script. I did it but it doesn't work too. And I tried to run it as "sudo -u". It works, I mean the window opens, but I obviously have no permissions to access video and audio equipment of the target user. This is my stumble point now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Apps should not be run with sudo; run them as your normal user to avoid malware infestation. Skype probably does that to prevent malware from spreading further, since *Microsoft Knows Best*.

Comment: I need it to run as root when I login into root user

Comment: Why? It's risky to run internet based apps as root.

Comment: @K7AAY are right, I meant to address OPs "I need to run as root ..." comment, not your answer and comment. Sorry, I will fix immediately.

Comment: @Bobarai, Running any apps as root, and especially internet based apps is the best and fastest way to get malware and even the Linux equivalent of viruses.You should NEVER EVER need to run apps as root, And also a fast way to break your system.

Comment: @Bobarai well, yes and no ... you _could_ impersonate a less privileged user by way of `su` or `sudo`. You could use namespaces to limit exposure (FireJail comes to mind). You could run this via `ssh unprivuser@localhost` with X11 forwarding. There are _so many ways_ to limit exposure. Especially exposure with an application that's proprietary with no source code available. I have _never ever_ seen any admin log on as `root` _interactively_ in a graphical desktop environment. On the terminal, sure. Otherwise this is a practice I only know from Windows admins.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Skype.
2. Add a new user to be a regular non-privileged user (for example, Skype-user) on whose behalf we will run Skype, so we'll be protected from external  attacks.
3. Add this user to two groups: "video" and "audio" to set it's permission   to access the related equipment.
4. Make changes in script file running Skype `/usr/bin/skypeforlinux`:

   - Add command `xhost +SI:localuser:skype-user` to get access to 
     Xterminal before the command executing Skype.
   - Change the command executing Skype:

     ```
     sudo -u skype-user -H nohup "$SKYPE_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@"  > "$SKYPE_LOGS/skype-startup.log" 2 > &1 &
     ```
5. Login as root and run the Skype application.
6. Check `/root/.config/skypeforlinux/logs/skype-startup.log` file if  it doesn't work.